# Mockito. Verify method param to be a particular class

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a method:

```
void putObject(<T extends BaseEntity> param)
```

Have some test where I mock this method, but I wonder, how to verify that method was called with parameter of particular class? Tried to do it in such ways:

```
verify(foo).putObject((SomeClass)anyObject());
------
verify(foo).putObject(any(SomeClass.class));
------
ArgumentCaptor<SomeClass> parameter = ArgumentCaptor
            .forClass(SomeClass.class);
verify(foo).putObject(parametr);
```

Works only the second variant with `any()`, but it doesn`t check class of`parameter`. So if it is possible to verify that method get any object of particular class?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

User Matcher [documentation](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/org/mockito/Matchers.html) **isA()** method.

`public static <T> T isA(java.lang.Class<T> clazz)`

That will solve your problem.

`verify(foo).putObject(isA(SomeClass.class));`

Answer (score 6):

Actually you can check with ArgumentCaptor.

```
ArgumentCaptor<SomeClass> parameterCaptor = ArgumentCaptor
            .forClass(SomeClass.class);
verify(foo).putObject(parameterCaptor.capture());

SomeClass instance = parameterCaptor.getValue();
// check intance.getX()
// check instance.getY()
```