# Mockito's Argument Captor Behavior

Tags: java, mockito

I am facing with issue where I need to track invocation of some method but only with specified argument parameter. See issue below

```
@Test
public void simpleTest() {
    ArgumentCaptor<Pear> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Pear.class);
    Action action = mock(Action.class);
    action.perform(new Pear());
    action.perform(new Apple());
    verify(action, times(1)).perform(captor.capture());
}

static class Action {

    public void perform(IFruit fruit) {}

}
static class Pear implements IFruit {}
static class Apple implements IFruit {}

interface IFruit {}
```

But getting :

```
org.mockito.exceptions.verification.TooManyActualInvocations: 
action.perform(<Capturing argument>);
Wanted 1 time:
But was 2 times. Undesired invocation:
..
```

What I am doing wrong? Mockito v 1.10

To be honest it is just for example and my code more complicated and I don't know, how many times perform will be invoked with Apple.class. It doesn't matter for me. I need to verify only call of perform(Pear.class)

**UPD:**
I need to verify that method with Pear.class was called once. Lets imagine that Action is Transaction and perform is save(DomainObject). So I need to be sure that save(MyDomainObject) was called once, but no matter how many Objects were saved before. This action is atomic for Test and I can't reset mock between these operations

Comment: You're calling it twice, and then trying to verify that you only called it once?

Comment: @Berger in his case it should be times(2) for test passing

Comment: But I want to verify only invocations of method with parameter type Pear.class. Any Idea How do it?

Comment: try `verify(action, times(1)).  perform(argumentThat(yourImplementation) )` to check the argument

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To verify the number of calls with `Pear` instances parameters, you may use :

```
verify(action, times(1)).perform(isA(Pear.class));
```

Cf. [Mockito. Verify method param to be a paticular class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14772208/mockito-verify-method-param-to-be-a-paticular-class)

Note that since Mockito 2.1, the following would also work :

```
verify(action, times(1)).perform(any(Pear.class));
```

cf. [public static  T any(Class type)](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.13.0/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#any-java.lang.Class-)

> ...This is an alias of: isA(Class)...
>
> ...Since mockito 2.1.0 any() and anyObject() are not anymore aliases of
> this method.

Comment: Just to clarify that: `any()` does actually match ANY(thing). The class there does NOT limit that in any way, it's just for compatibility to Java's type checking.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz : Just searched that point, it seems that since Mockito 2.1, `any(Class)` is an alias of `isA(Class)`, not of `any()/anyObject()` anymore, see : https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.13.0/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#any-java.lang.Class-

Answer (score 3):

Workaround using a custom captor class

```
  @Test
  public void simpleTest() {
    MyArgumentCaptor pearCaptor = new MyArgumentCaptor(Pear.class);
    Action action = mock(Action.class);

    action.perform(new Pear());
    action.perform(new Apple());

    verify(action, times(1)).perform((IFruit) argThat(pearCaptor));

    System.out.println(pearCaptor.getMatchedObj());
  }


  class MyArgumentCaptor extends InstanceOf {
    private Object matchedObj;

    MyArgumentCaptor(Class<?> clazz) {
      super(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object actual) {
      boolean matches = super.matches(actual);
      if (matches) {
        matchedObj = actual;
      }
      return matches;
    }

    Object getMatchedObj() {
      return matchedObj;
    }
  }
```

Comment: these 2 lines of your code saved my time.And thankyou so much .............                                                                    verify(action, times(1)).perform((IFruit) argThat(pearCaptor));

    System.out.println(pearCaptor.getMatchedObj());

Answer (score 0):

You are calling action twice, but expecting one call (`times(1)`). Try with `times(2)` if it is called twice or omit it if you don't care how many times you call it.

```
action.perform(new Pear());
action.perform(new Apple());
```

Comment: To be honest it is just for example and my code more complicated and I don't know, how many times perform will be invoked with Apple.class. It doesn't matter for me. I need to verify only call of perform(Pear.class)

Comment: Updated the description if you dont care about how many times the method is called.

Comment: I need to verify that method with Pear.class was called once. Lets imagine that Action is Transaction and perform is save(DomainObject). So I need to be sure that save(MyDomainObject) was called once, but no matter how many Objects were saved before. This action is atomic for Test and I can't reset mock between these operations